# WiFi Transmitter/Receiver

Tags: wifi, transmitter, receiver, transceiver

I want to create a small, battery-powered electronic device to detect the presence of AC voltage after a power outage. It would then transmit notifications to that effect.

The two components of the device are an inductive (contactless) voltage detector and a transmitter/receiver to send the notifications and/or emails via WiFi and to receive acknowledgment notifications.

I have a schematic for the detector using a 555 IC, but I’m at a loss as far as the Tx/Rx circuitry and components are concerned. Any direction or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a question with no short answer.  Each of the major blocks of this project - non-contact voltage detection, wifi transceiver, (assumed) microcontroller, and the coding and power circuitry to tie it all together could be several questions on their own.  I would go to one of the online electronics stores that sell modules that are designed to work together with a minimum of fuss and come with extra documentation (like quickstart guides) aside from datasheets (which are also very important!) and get each block working as independently as possible before getting them to work together.

Comment: Why is there a need for contactless detection? This could be something like a raspberry Pi connected to a power supply plugged into the wall. When it has power, it sends notifications. Is there any need to complicate it? And to make it battery powered? What for? In fact, typically you don't even need an extra device. Pinging the router from outside, e.g. from one of the many cloud worker services, will do this detection indirectly (assuming the router doesn't die/lose connectivity).

Comment: @Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica, I live in rural Maine.  With an outage, a portable generator is plugged directly to the service panel.  No transfer switch.  There's a lockout so either the main or the generator breaker is on.
The detector will have an led and a buzzer.  I’ll try locating it by the service panel but the detector might not be sensitive enough to work through the wall and the conduit, and the branch circuits powered by the generator might interfere with detecting voltage on the mains.  If it works, no need for a tx.  If not, I’ll put it by the meter with a tx.

Answer (score 1):

You will need/can try with the following components:

- Inductive Voltage Detector: As you possess a 555 timer IC schematic, utilize this circuit for detecting voltage.
- Microcontroller: A microcontroller, such as the ESP8266 or ESP32 with built-in Wi-Fi, is necessary to interpret voltage detector signals and manage Wi-Fi module communication.
- Wi-Fi Module: If your chosen microcontroller lacks Wi-Fi, supplement it with an external module like the ESP8266 or ESP01 to facilitate internet communication.
- Power Supply: A battery and voltage regulator are essential to maintain stable power for the microcontroller and associated components in a battery-powered device.

Now, there are several ways to do this, but I recommend the following steps:

1. Link the inductive voltage detector and microcontroller by connecting the 555 timer IC circuit output to a microcontroller digital input pin. This connection enables the microcontroller to read signals and identify AC voltage presence.
2. Program the microcontroller, using the Arduino IDE and relevant Wi-Fi, email, and notification libraries, to connect to Wi-Fi and transmit notifications upon detecting AC voltage. The ESP8266 or ESP32 are suitable choices.
3. Establish a notification reception service, such as IFTTT or a custom server, which will manage email or acknowledgement notification delivery back to the device.
4. Connect the battery to the voltage regulator, providing power to the microcontroller and other components. Carefully select an appropriate battery type and capacity to ensure ample device runtime.
5. Enclose the device, considering ventilation requirements, battery accessibility, and optimal positioning of the inductive voltage detector for effective detection.

If memory serves me correctly, this was more or less what I did to assemble a device that detects the presence of AC voltage and could send notifications wirelessly.